# PHP: Set max_file_uploads for one file rather than php.ini

Tags: php, upload, ini

Like many variables in PHP using ini_set() on a page doesn't actually work.

I've recently upgraded my PHP version and found that my multiple image uploader is now capped. After 3 hours of frustration, I've found that my new PHP install has the new "max_file_uploads" parameter set to "20".

So only the first 7 images get uploaded (each is in three sizes, 7*3=21).

I can now change my php.ini value of "max_file_uploads" to 300, but I'd rather not do that side wide.

Is there any way to set that value just for a single file (upload.php)? Could a .htaccess file be used for this?

Comment: @Jenkz it seems not to be possible to manually alter the setting, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> **Correction:** max_file_uploads can NOT be changed outside php.ini. See [PHP "Bug" #50684](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50684&edit=1)

Comment: At least in the comment section of the bug report:
"ini_set would never work because file uploads happen before the PHP script is 
executed, so by the time you call ini_set() it would be too late." And at least I am still unable to set now in 2019

Answer (score 6):

Yes it can be changed. 
Use the .htaccess file and add this:

```
php_value max_file_uploads 40
```

example, i use this in my .htaccess in the folder:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 25M
php_value post_max_size 25M
php_value max_file_uploads 1000
```

;)

damian rossi

Comment: Actually , this does not work for every site. If you are using PHP > 5.5 you can specifiy a file named ".user.ini" in the relevant directory